# Error Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas,

Tengo un tabla creada a través de código en java. La tabla se crea sin ningún tipo de error, pero cuando voy a MySQL y pulso 2 veces sobre cualquier celda, me muestra una ventana emergente que indica `Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'`. Además, aquellas celdas que tienen más de X letras no se muestran completas. Dejo una imagen para que sea visual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que teneos el siguiente:

```
public class Conectate {
private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
private String pass = "";
private String usuario = "root";
public Connection con;

public Conectate(Map<String,  Map<String, Item>> gamesByCountry, Map<String, String> codesByTitle,Map<String, String> countries) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


        //CREAMOS LA TABLA
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(200),"
                + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50))");

        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, Lanzamiento"
            + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?"
            + ",?,?,?,?,?"
            + ")");


        for (String titulo : codesByTitle.keySet()) {                 
            String code = codesByTitle.get(titulo);
                for (String country : countries.keySet()) {
            Item game = gamesByCountry.get(country).get(code);

                            if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {                                  
                                ps.setString(1,titulo);
                            }

            if (game != null) {

                                    if (country.equals("Estados Unidos")) {
                                        ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                                        ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                                        ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                                        ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA));
                                        ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                                    }

                                    if (country.equals("España")) {
                                        ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                                        ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                                        ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                                    }

            }
                }
                ps.executeUpdate();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
    }

}

public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
String Str="";
if(Obj!=null){
    Str = Obj.toString();
}
return Str;
}


}
```

Algo tendré que estar haciendo mal, pero no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Si consultas la base de datos desde java, funciona correctamente? Quizá el error sea de phpmyadmin.

Comment: Cual es el query que realizas para la consulta? agregalo

Comment: @Jorgesys En el primer post está todo el código. Si con consulta te refieres a buscar algún dato en la base de datos desde java, no tengo nada de eso, simplemente creo una tabla si no existe y vuelco todos los datos.

Comment: @ArieCwHat No he probado a hacerlo, estoy modificando el código para probarlo pero no he hecho nunca una consulta que no sea agregar información desde java.

Comment: podrías intentarlo? o usar otro programa para ver la base de datos como "mysql workbench" o "navicat"

Comment: Si te fijas en tu pantalla de PhpMyadmin verás algo que dice SQL. Si te vas ahí verás la consulta en código SQL de los datos que ves en pantalla. Si copias ese código y lo pegas aquí editando tu pregunta podría ser útil para encontrar la causa, que según dice está en la cláusula WHERE de la consulta.

Comment: Probadte crear la tabla sin mayusculas ni guiones, ni nada que obligue a entrecomillar el nombre del campo?

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo único que me pone es `SELECT * FROM `info_XboxOne` WHERE 1`, pero vamos, que eso mismo me pone en otras tablas que no me dan ningún problema.

Comment: El WHERE no lleva ``

Comment: @A.Cedano No las lleva, el problema es que al querer citar el texto las comillas se van al carajo, lo que aparece es `SELECT * FROM 'info_XboxOne' WHERE 1`

Comment: Pero una pregunta ¿ los datos de tu captura de pantalla provienen de una sola tabla o de varias? Según la consulta son de una sola. Te da el mismo problema si abres, cierras y escribes manualmente tu SQL: SELECT * FROM LATABLA sin usar el WHERE... para probar. ¿Has modificado el nombre de alguna columna? ¿Has optimizado la tabla, borrado los caché? Eso está en la pestaña Operaciones si mal no recuerdo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema. Prueba en el apartado de "Opciones extra" a activar la opción de "Textos completos"

[image: Mostrar textos completos]

Espero que te sirva